# $_POST INSIDE htmlentities INSIDE isset

Tags: php

I feel like it should works my logic is correct and no error showing on hosting text editor yet error

`Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)` showed up

here's the code

```
if (!isset(htmlentities($_POST['test'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8")) == "test123") {
  echo "ERROR!1<br>";
}
```

should i first save $_POST['test'] on different variable and htmlentities it or what's the best approach?

Comment: [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) returns a boolean value. Why are you trying to compare it to a string...? Can you share why you haven't opted to take the error message's advice and compare the result of the `htmlentities()` function to `null`...? `isset()` is largely useful for variables, not expressions themselves.

Comment: "*what's the best approach?*" Questions asking about the "best" anything are inherently subjective and thus explicitly off-topic here per the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Do you probably want to check for `isset($_POST['test'])`  instead?

Comment: Given the string you're trying to compare to has no HTML entities, why bother with all that noise? `if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "test") === "test123")`

Comment: @Phil that's actually much simpler and neat looking

Comment: _"I feel like it should works my logic is correct"_ - no, of course it isn't. The purpose of `isset` is to check if a variable even _exists_, yet you try to apply `htmlspecialchars` to it _before_ you even did that.

Comment: @CBroe ohhh that's explanation make sense and thats what the error actually means since php is asynchronous it can't "jump" doing `htmlentities` first before the `isset`

Comment: That doesn't mean "asynchronous", it is simply how the evaluation of nested function calls works - the innermost function is evaluated first, and then the result of that call is passed on to the next "outer" function.

Answer (score 2):

The code for what you defined inside the question should look like this

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
  if (htmlentities($_POST['test'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8") !== "test123") {
    echo "ERROR!1<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "ERROR!1<br>";
}
```

I have used 2 if statements on the first section so the line is not that long. If you want, feel free to combine them into a single statement.

On the other hand, do you really need  the `htmlentities` function? You should check your logic, I am unable to tell based on the question. If not then the code looks like this:

```
if (!isset($_POST['test']) {
  echo "ERROR!1<br>";
} else {
  if ($_POST['test'] !== "test123") {
    echo "ERROR!1<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

i fixed it ...I just store htmlentities to outside variable and instead of comparing it i negate it i think it much aesthetic

```
$test = htmlentities($_POST['test'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8");
if ($test != "test123") {
  echo "ERROR!!<br>";
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you think you're doing here? `htmlentities()` is an output function. The only reason to apply it to `$_POST[]` is if you're about to echo an element to the browser. In any case, the only string that produces `test123` when pased through `htmlentities()` is `test123`. You might as well test for it directly. This solution is entirely redundant.